# JSONP works in jQuery but not in mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools, jsonp

I'm trying to convert my code to Mootools (I like the coding paradigm better).

I am doing cross-domain AJAX where I own both domains (closed network).  I am just requesting simple JSON from my server.  I get these errors in Mootools (jQuery works):

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.`
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

`var url = http://localhost:3000/`

Server:

```
var http = require('http'),
    json = {"hi" : false};

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(json));
}).listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server on " + 3000);
});
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Mootools:

```
var myRequest = new Request.JSONP({
    url: url,
    onComplete: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
myRequest.send();
```

I've tried adding these headers to no avail.:

```
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

This seems to be a client-side thing and not a server-side thing since it works in jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does URL look like?  jQuery figures out it's a JSONP request by adding `?callback=` or `?foo=` to the url.  `Request.JSONP` instead uses an option `callbackKey`.

There's no `method` option for JSONP (in any library), since it's just injecting a script tag.

```
var myRequest = new Request.JSONP({
  url: url,
  callbackKey: 'callback'
  onComplete: function(data){}
}).send();
```

I have a feeling, however, you aren't using JSONP, but rather XHR with JSON.  If that's the case, use `Request.JSON`, not `Request.JSONP`.

---

*Edit*

Since it sounds, from the comments on this answer, that you're not using JSONP, just do this:

```
new Request.JSON({
  url: url,
  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: function (data){
    console.log(data)
  }
}).send()
```

---

*Edit 2*

To change the request headers just add them as an option:

```
new Request.JSON({
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Accept': 'text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*'
  },
  url: url,
  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: function (data){
    console.log(data)
  }
}).send()
```

Comment: It's just a regular url with a port. E.g. stackoverflow.com:3000.  My host is something like mydomain.com:4000.  Note: these aren't the urls, just examples.

Comment: Apparently my coworker restricted the headers on the webserver. I fixed it by just using XmlHttpRequest.  For some reason Mootools was intent on putting extra headers that I didn't need.  Do you know how to remove the default headers?

Comment: I'm marking yours as correct even though it didn't directly resolve my question.  As my previous comment says, I got it working by avoiding Mootools' Request. Thanks anyway for the response!

Comment: headers is an option like `url` ... put whatever you want in there.  Updating the answer.

Comment: +1 I just moved to Ender.js (I know, kinda ADD), but I will use MooTools packages, and this seems like it should work! Thanks!

Comment: I actually added all the MooTools modules to NPM and therefore ender (gave a presentation in Lehi, right by you, you should have come!) just do this: `ender build mootools-request-json`

Comment: @rpflo Cool! I didn't know about it, I would have come if I could.  Anyway, I'll have to check out the MooTools stuff on NPM. I'm getting tired of jQuery-isms.

Answer (score 1):

You had a syntax error in your code.

```
var myRequest = new Request.JSONP({
    url: url,
    method: 'get',
    onComplete: function(data){}
});
myRequest.send();
```

Also, the response should be wrapped with callback function, example: http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/yVbYQ/

Comment: I don't have much control over the response, but I trust it's source. It's generated dynamically.  As for the syntax error, if that's my problem, I'd be really embarrassed.  I'll check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call should be like this

```
          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:17370/SampleService.asmx/HelloWorld",
                data: "{}",
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "jsonp",
               async:false,
                success:function(data,status){
                    alert(data);

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error Occured!" + " | " +
                    XMLHttpRequest + " | " + textStatus + " | " +
                    errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

Your server side method should not return simple string it should return response in jsonp format for that you need to follow this blog:

http://msrtechnical.blogspot.in/